# Display code output to mainwindow in QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have some code that I wrote in geany that distributes a total of 28 numbers to 7 letters.

Here is the code in Geany:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int specialstats()
{
    int stats[7], x;
    for (x=0;x<7;x++) stats[x]=0;
    for (x=0;x<28;x++) stats[rand()%7]++;
    cout<<"S: "<<stats[0]<<"\n";
    cout<<"P: "<<stats[1]<<"\n";
    cout<<"E: "<<stats[2]<<"\n";
    cout<<"C: "<<stats[3]<<"\n";
    cout<<"I: "<<stats[4]<<"\n";
    cout<<"A: "<<stats[5]<<"\n";
    cout<<"L: "<<stats[6]<<"\n";
    return 0;

}
int main() 
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    specialstats();
    return 0;
}
```

So basically I want to put it into QT and have the output of that code show up in a window. Here is what I have there:

again.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = again
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Here is my mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Here is my main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>  
#include <QLabel>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    int stats[7];
    int x;
    for (x=0;x<7;x++) stats[x]=0;
    for (x=0;x<28;x++) stats[rand()%7]++;
    QMainWindow mainWindow;
    QLabel *label2 = new QLabel (&mainWindow);
    label2->setText("S: "<<stats[0]<<"\n");
    std::cout<<"P: \033[1;32m"<<stats[1]<<"\033[0m\n";
    std::cout<<"E: \033[1;32m"<<stats[2]<<"\033[0m\n";
    std::cout<<"C: \033[1;32m"<<stats[3]<<"\033[0m\n";
    std::cout<<"I: \033[1;32m"<<stats[4]<<"\033[0m\n";
    std::cout<<"A: \033[1;32m"<<stats[5]<<"\033[0m\n";
    std::cout<<"L: \033[1;32m"<<stats[6]<<"\033[0m\n";
    mainWindow.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And my mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
   {
     delete ui;
   }
```

The errors that I get when I try to run this are, and are in my main.cpp:

`/home/administrator/again/main.cpp:20: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [5]' and 'int' to binary 'operator<<'
         label2->setText("S: \n"<<stats[0]<<"\n");
                                         ^`

and,

`[main.o] Error 1`

What do I do to make the output of this text show up in the window?? In Geany, it outputs to a console and works flawlessly. I just want to try new things out and I am a beginner, so go easy on me.

Comment: A friendly advice: try using QtCreator (the official IDE for Qt). It will be easier for you to start working your way through the Qt jungle. QtCreator is generally not only great for Qt projects but for general C++ applications (especially those that use `cmake`). When using an editor such as Geany that doesn't provide the additional features that QtCreator has for specific Qt-things you make your coding experience worse omho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concatenate c-style strings with the << operator.

To fix your compile error, change line 20 of main.cpp to e.g.:

```
label2->setText(QString("S: %1").arg(stats[0]));
```

QString is the default type to handle strings in Qt. You can find fine documentation about QString here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Besides the compiler error, your code has some issues with how you draw into QMainWindow. Essentially, besides the QMainWindow, you need:

- a widget
- set the widget as 'centralWidget' of QMainWindow
- define a layout for this widget
- and add all the QLabels you want to show to this layout

These operations could be done in your MainWindow class. Or as you did, in the main function.

Here is a very crude alternative implementation of your main function. There is still a lot of room for improvement, but it should demonstrate the basic principle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    int stats[7] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    QWidget *centralWidget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(&w);

    centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    w.setCentralWidget(centralWidget);

    QLabel *label[7];

    for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
        label[i] = new QLabel (QString("S: %1").arg(stats[i]));
        layout->addWidget(label[i]);
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

If you use QtDesigner, you don't have to worry about how to define the layouts programmatically, but you can use a nice and intuitive tool to help you with the process of designing the layout and appearance of the windows.
QtDesigner generates the *.ui files.

Comment: I really don't see why one would want to create a whole main window widget instead of just a simple widget when such a task has to be fulfilled as displaying some text.

Comment: `label2->setText(QString("S: %1").arg(stats[0]));` did work for me. However, \n doesn't seem to work when starting a new line. Is there some other alternative?

Comment: What do you mean? '\n' inside a QString for a QLabel does work for me. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to print multiple labels? Then I would recommend looking into layouting your MainWindow with QtDesigner.